# How to display recent upgrade messages?

Tags: upgrade

Trying to semi-automate my upgrade process by using "drush civicrm-upgrade", but I'm concerned that any critical messages, e.g. that default message templates have changed, won't be displayed in the shell.

I have a vague recollection that there exists a URL which will display the site's most recent upgrade messages, but I can't find it now in the documentation. Is there such a URL?

And does drush civicrm-upgrade display such messages in the shell?

Answer (score 5):

I just ran `drush civicrm-upgrade-db` and saw [upgrade messages in the output](https://gist.github.com/xurizaemon/53ad9052794e49abe681).

While the formatting could certainly be improved, this does seem to work (in some cases?).

As Coleman notes below and in [CRM-16946](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16946) - *pre* upgrade warnings/notices are not displayed by Drush upgrade, while *post* upgrade notices are.

Comment: Agreed - I've used drush civicrm-upgrade-db a bunch.  Upgrade messages appear as raw HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Post-upgrade messages do display via drush. However pre-upgrade warnings do not. There's an [open issue](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16946) for this, and help would be most welcome.

Comment: Have added a comment on the issue as this is not my experience (tested just now).